# Docker - see where things are installed, with dokku

Tags: lua, containers, docker, dokku

I'm using [docker](http://www.docker.com/) with [dokku](https://github.com/progrium/dokku). Trying to debug issue with https://github.com/leafo/heroku-buildpack-lua/. **Is it possible to see and check content of docker container?**

```
vagrant@dokku:~$ dokku logs dokku.me -t
/app/.profile.d/config_vars: line 3: /app/packages/lib/lua/5.1/?.so: No such file or directory
/app/.profile.d/config_vars: line 4: /app/packages/share/lua/5.1/?.lua: No such file or directory
/app/.profile.d/config_vars: line 4: /app/packages/share/lua/5.1/?/init.lua: No such file or directory
lua: /app/bin/lapis:3: module 'lapis.cmd.actions' not found:
no field package.preload['lapis.cmd.actions']
no file './lapis/cmd/actions.lua'
no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/lapis/cmd/actions.lua'
no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/lapis/cmd/actions/init.lua'
no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/lapis/cmd/actions.lua'
no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/lapis/cmd/actions/init.lua'
no file './lapis/cmd/actions.so'
no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/lapis/cmd/actions.so'
no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/loadall.so'
no file './lapis.so'
no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/lapis.so'
no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/loadall.so'

stack traceback:
[C]: in function 'require'
/app/bin/lapis:3: in main chunk
[C]: ?
```

I'm suggesting that [lapis](https://github.com/leafo/lapis/tree/master/lapis) was installed somewhere not in the lua loadpath..

Thanks!

Comment: Have you done a search on your system to locate it?

Answer (score 0):

Considering:

- App name is `yourapp`
- Server name is `domain.com`
- Having configured `RequestTTY true` in your `~/.ssh/config` section for `domain.com`

You can run:

`ssh dokku@domain.com run yourapp ls -la`

And it will output your deployed app's directory. Same applies with `cd` or any other command, the syntax is the same: `ssh dokku@domain.com run yourapp <command>`

I think if you're ssh'd into the server, you could run `dokku run yourapp <command>`

Source: http://progrium.viewdocs.io/dokku/remote-commands